# Proving Fermat's little theorem directly

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I'm trying to prove Fermat's little theorem directly with only the definition of congruence.

> **Fermat's theorem:** If $p$ prime and $a$ is an integer such that $(a,p)=1$, then $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\ (mod\ p)$.
>
> *Proof:*
>
> Each element of $1,2,\ldots,p-1$ is congruent modulo $p$ to one and
>   only one element of these $a,2a,\ldots,(p-1)a$ and vice-versa.
>
> Let $n_1a$ with $0\le n_1\le p-1$. By Division Algorithm there exist
>   $q$ and $r$ integers such that $0\le r\le p-1$ and $n_1a=pq+r$ ($r\neq
>  0$ because $(a,p)=1$). Thus $n_1a\equiv r\ (mod\ p)$ with $1\le r\le
>  p-1$.
>
> Suppose now $n_1a\equiv n_2\ (mod\ p)$ and $n_1a\equiv n_3\ (mod\ p)$
>   with $1\le n_1,n_2,n_3\le p-1$, then is easy to see $n_2=n_3$.
>
> On the other hand, if $n_1a\equiv n_3\ (mod\ p)$ and $n_2a\equiv n_3\
>  (mod\ p)$ with $1\le n_1,n_2,n_3\le p-1$, then $n_1\equiv n_2\ (mod\ p)$ (since (a,p)=1, we can cancel the $a$'s). Therefore, $p|(n_1-n_2)$ which implies $n_1-n_2=0$ and $n_1=n_2$.
>
> Thus, $a\cdot 2a\cdot\ldots\cdot(p-1)a\equiv 1\cdot2\cdot\ldots\cdot
>  p-1\ (mod\ p)$ implies $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\ (mod\ p)$.

Does it miss something?

Comment: This is more or less it. The crux of the proof is to note that the map $n \mapsto a n$ is injective mod $p$.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't miss anything.

However, I have two quick comments :

- the part beginning with "suppose now" is useless. It is clear that $n_1a$ has only one rest in the division by $p$
- the part beginning with "on the other hand" is where you would need more details. If $n_1a \equiv n_2a \mod{p}$, then $a(n_1-n_2) \equiv 0 \mod{p}$, which is impossible since $n_1-n_2 \in [2-p,p-2]$ is prime with $p$ and so is $a$. Whether it is "easy to see" or not depends on your audience, and it is the subtle point of this proof, so you might as well write it

Comment: Please see my edit after "on the other hand", thanks!

Comment: Yes, that is clearer